# Why does our Coldfusion server require a daily restart?

Tags: coldfusion

Our Coldfusion server requires a daily restart using command

`-jar jrun.jar -start coldfusion`

Not sure why it is stopping daily. Someone please help to resolve this.

We have coldfusion running on a UNIX server.

Server.log has the below:

> "Warning","14","04/22/15","16:48:38",,"Template:
>   /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 8 seconds."
>
> "Warning","12","04/22/15","16:50:17",,"Template:
>   /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 22 seconds."
>
> "Warning","14","04/22/15","16:50:20",,"Template:
>   /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 27 seconds."
>
> "Warning","9","04/22/15","16:53:20",,"Template:
>   /cfide/administrator/logging/downloadlog.cfm, Ran: 2 seconds."
>
> "Warning","9","04/22/15","16:54:23",,"Template:
>   /cfide/administrator/logging/downloadlog.cfm, Ran: 2 seconds."

Webserver.log

> Webserver "Error","13","04/22/15","13:13:52",,"An error occurred while
>   attempting to establish a connection to the server.
>
> The most likely
>   cause of this problem is that the server is not currently running.
>   Verify that the server is running and restart it if necessary.
>
> Unix
>   error number 2 occurred: No such file or directory"

Application.log

> Wed Apr 22 16:48:26 2015
> Browser: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E)
> Remote Address: 10.2.200.119

```
opt/coldfusion/JRun/logs>ls -lrt
total 2284
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   nobody         0 May 27  2006 default-out.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev      99954 Jan 14 00:45 default-event_5.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev     100017 Feb  6 16:57 default-event_4.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev      99973 Mar  5 00:45 default-event_3.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev      99961 Mar 29 17:01 default-event_2.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev      99981 Apr 22 00:45 default-event_1.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   nobody    610627 Apr 23 00:45 default-err.log
-rw-r--r--   1 cf5dev   cfdev       6706 Apr 23 00:45 default-event.log
```

Default-event.log

```
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying jcp
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying demo-app
04/23 00:45:20 error (jcp) Socket closed [java.net.SocketException: Socket closed]
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.setOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:186)
            at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:377)
            at allaire.jrun.jrpp.ProxyService.createRunnable(ProxyService.java:32)
            at allaire.jrun.ThreadPool.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:175)
            at allaire.jrun.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:72)

04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying default-app
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) FlashGenerator: destroy
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying control
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying monitor
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying logging
04/23 00:45:20 info (JRun) Destroying scheduler
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading monitor
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading license
04/23 00:45:28 info (license) Enabling unlimited concurrency for Enterprise
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading control
04/23 00:45:28 info (control) control listening on 127.0.0.1:22719
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading default-app
04/23 00:45:28 info (default-app) Starting default-app: Default User Application - Default application for getting started
04/23 00:45:28 info (default-app) Loading scheduler
04/23 00:45:28 info (default-app) Loading logging
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading session
04/23 00:45:28 info (session) Loading persistence storage provider 'file'
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading authentication
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading propfile
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading jsp
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) Loading file
04/23 00:45:28 info (JRun) FlashGenerator: init
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) default-app Ready
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) Loading demo-app
04/23 00:45:29 info (demo-app) Starting demo-app: JRun Demo - JRun Demo
04/23 00:45:29 info (demo-app) Loading scheduler
04/23 00:45:29 info (demo-app) Loading logging
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) Loading session
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) Loading authentication
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) Loading propfile
04/23 00:45:29 info (session) Loading persistence storage provider 'file'
04/23 00:45:29 info (JRun) Loading jsp
04/23 00:45:30 info (JRun) Loading file
04/23 00:45:30 info (JRun) demo-app Ready
04/23 00:45:30 info (JRun) Loading jcp
04/23 00:45:30 info (jcp) jcp listening on 127.0.0.1:22718
04/23 00:45:30 info (JRun) default Ready
```

Default-err.log

```
Operating System: SunOS Version 5.10
Java Virtual Machine: mixed mode from Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRun 3.0 3.02a.11569 Starting default...
Current Locale: en
Loading scheduler
Loading logging
Operating System: SunOS Version 5.10
Java Virtual Machine: mixed mode from Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRun 3.0 3.02a.11569 Starting default...
Current Locale: en
Loading scheduler
Loading logging
Operating System: SunOS Version 5.10
Java Virtual Machine: mixed mode from Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRun 3.0 3.02a.11569 Starting default...
Current Locale: en
Loading scheduler
Loading logging
Operating System: SunOS Version 5.10
Java Virtual Machine: mixed mode from Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRun 3.0 3.02a.11569 Starting default...
Current Locale: en
Loading scheduler
Loading logging
Operating System: SunOS Version 5.10
Java Virtual Machine: mixed mode from Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRun 3.0 3.02a.11569 Starting default...
Current Locale: en
Loading scheduler
Loading logging
```

Which of the log files will give the exact information about this stopping issue? 
There is no log file named as coldfusion-out.log

Comment: Go Services through services.msc command in run. Search for 'Coldfusion Application Server' in properties make Start Up Type as 'Automatic'.

Comment: We have coldfusion running in unix server.kindly suggest me what can be done for this.

Comment: Did you check the server.log?

Comment: Server.log has the below:
"Warning","14","04/22/15","16:48:38",,"Template: /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 8 seconds."
"Warning","12","04/22/15","16:50:17",,"Template: /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 22 seconds."
"Warning","14","04/22/15","16:50:20",,"Template: /cfide/cf5dev/break/Cage/cage.cfm, Ran: 27 seconds."
"Warning","9","04/22/15","16:53:20",,"Template: /cfide/administrator/logging/downloadlog.cfm, Ran: 2 seconds."
"Warning","9","04/22/15","16:54:23",,"Template: /cfide/administrator/logging/downloadlog.cfm, Ran: 2 seconds."

Comment: Webserver.log  Webserver
 
"Error","13","04/22/15","13:13:52",,"An error occurred while attempting to establish a connection to the server.<P> The most likely cause of this problem is that the server is not currently running. Verify that the server is running and restart it if necessary.  <P>Unix error number 2 occurred: No such file or directory"

Comment: Which of the log files will give the exact information about this stopping issue?

Comment: Rather than having the log output in the comments, you might find it better for all concerned to edit your question with the log output in the main question.

Comment: As @Jarede mentioned, update the question with server.log, application.log, coldfusion-out.log and

Comment: coldfusion-out.log please

Comment: Use some monitoring tools to check what's happening to your threads and memory just as the slowdown happens. Also, this is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow. Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: @AnitKumar, ColdFusion on JRun is CF 9 or earlier.  I don't think that there is a coldfusion-out.log file.

Comment: @ScottJibben CF9 Single Server - \ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log and CF9 MultiServer - \JRun4\logs\cfusion-out.log